# How to PHPUnit test for general errors like "undefined index"

Tags: php, phpunit

Let's say I have this very basic class:

```
class MyClass {

    private $_counters = [
        'counter1' => 0,
    ];

    public function plus($counter) {
        $this->_counters[$counter]++;
    }

}
```

Now there's a change to the code so that it doesn't break if the $counter does not exist:

```
public function plus($counter) {
    if (array_key_exists($counter, $this->_counters)) {
        $this->_counters[$counter]++;
    }
}
```

How would I go about testing this for a possible regression that results in an "undefined index" error being thrown?

Would simply calling the function `plus()` with a non-existing `$counter` be enough? When all is good nothing happens but if a regression removed the `array_key_exists()` check for example, the "undefined index" would be thrown.

I'm quite new to unit testing so am I missing a better way to test this situation? It feels a bit weird to write a testcase without asserting something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a test that calls `plus()` with something that doesn't exist like `foo` as you stated.

Though testing that an `undefined index` notice isn't thrown isn't really what you are testing.  This specifies that your class contains all the counters in an array.  This is an implementation detail of your class that your tests shouldn't care about.

You could write the class such that each of the counters is a property of the class instead.  Really want you want to decide is what should happen when an counter that doesn't exist is used in the `plus` method.

Your tests should test for behaviors of the class.  So for non-existent counters you will need to decide what should happen.  An exception is thrown, a message logged or nothing at all.